# How to send the result to the client via the gRPC StreamObserver in a different thread?

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc

I have an exciting situation in my application.

In the typical scenario, the client sends a gRPC request to the Server. When the server(RequestHandler) receives the request, it will save the streamObserver in a ThreadLocal variable and send a ProcessRequest event using the ApplicationEventPublisher to process the request. The RequestHandler is listening to another event RequestProcessed to get the result. At this time, the streamObserver will be accessed from the ThreadLocal variable, and using the onNext method the result will be sent to the Client.

The special case happens when the result is coming from a different thread where I don't have the access to the streamObserver. What is the best way to handle such a scenario?

The solution I have in my mind is to introduce another gRPC client to the Server and a gRPC server to the client. This way, the server can initiate a new gRPC request to the client. I am not sure if this is the best solution since I am going to have 2 gRPC servers in both the client application and the server application.

I am using 2 spring boot microservices as the client application and the server application.

Client code

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GrpcClient {
    private final ClientServiceGrpc.ClientServiceGrpc serviceStub;
    private final StreamObserver<ProcessedResult> streamObserver;

    @ServiceActivator
    public void send(ProcessRequest request) {
         serviceStub.process(request, streamObserver);
    }
}
```

Server code

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProcessRequestHandler extends AbstractRequestHandler<ProcessRequest, ProcessedResult> {
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
    private final ThreadLocal<StreamObserver<ProcessedResult>> localObserver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Transactional
    public void handleRequest(ProcessRequest request, StreamObserver<ProcessedResult> response) {
        try {
            localObserver.set(response);
            publisher.publishEvent(new ProcessRequest(request));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            response.onError(t);
            localObserver.remove();
            throw t;
        }
    }

    @TransactionalEventListener()
    public void handleResponseComingFromDifferentThread(RequestProcessed result) {
    // accessing response by localObserver.get() is not possible here since this is a different thread. How can I use this result to invoke the response.onNext(result) ?
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you use a Map to save the `StreamObserver` between the 2 threads? So the different thread which receives `RequestProcessed` can use the Map to retrieve the `StreamObserver` using some agreed upon unique key and use it to send back the response?

Comment: Good point. The server will have multiple instances. `RequestProcessed` could be in a different instance.

Comment: Hmmm, it wasn't clear from the original post that this involved multiple instances (processes).  You will have to make sure `RequestProcessed` comes to the same instance for this to work